# android border around view not working

Tags: android, border, android-relativelayout, shapes

I got the following result with 5 views(top,bottom,left,right,centre) in a `RelativeLayout`, then placing a camera preview into it.

[image: camera preview]

What I also wanted is to draw a border around the center view. I used a shape drawable for it but it didn't work. The border works for all the views in the relative layout except center.

How can I draw border around it?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#80000000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#80000000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/top"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#80000000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/top"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#80000000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
            android:layout_below="@id/top"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/left"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/right"
            android:background="@drawable/border_red" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Capture" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the border_red.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#FF0000" android:width="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are giving margin to the `View` which was way too much to fit in the area.That is why your center `View` was not visible.Replace your center `View` with the below `View` code.This works for me, hope it works for you too 
eg.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
        android:background="@drawable/border_red" />
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative Solution :-

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/right"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#00000000"/>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: oh...!! it will definitely work when you place camera preview in `View`.i.e.you have to add a child `View` in it.

Comment: the camera preview is put on the entire RelativeLayout. The center view is useless. I added it just to show border.

Comment: can we put a view inside another view?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce Height to `5dp` like this `android:layout_height="5dp"` in   `View`

Horizontal line

```
  <View
     android:id="@+id/view"
     android:background="#FF4500"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="2dp"     
     android:layout_below="@+id/listview_id" />
```

vertical line

```
 <View
   android:id="@+id/view"
   android:background="#FF4500"
   android:layout_width="2dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"     />
```

Comment: this is not even related to what I am trying to do.